# How to run PHP built-in server in quiet mode?

Tags: php

How do I silent output of PHP built-in server?

I tried

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:80 -t public/ > /dev/null
```

but it still output

```
[Thu Jun 11 13:08:53 2015] 127.0.0.1:60963 [200]: /
```

Comment: Try php -S 127.0.0.1:80 -t public/ >& /dev/null. It redirects standard output and standard error

Comment: Could anyone close the answer now? :)

Comment: I wonder how could we close an *answer* @sitilge ?

Comment: My bad, I meant the question... @code-jaff

Comment: Perhaps @c4pone can move the comment to an answer and I click accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
php -q -S 127.0.0.1:80 -t public/
```

use -q option for Quiet-mode

Comment: Remember to use `-q` before `-S`

Answer (score 9):

The character > just redirects standard output. If you want to redirect standard error and standard output you can use >&

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:80 -t public/ >& /dev/null
```

Comment: how to close or terminal server.

Comment: @dipenparmar12 you can do `killall php`