# Silence PHP 7.4.8 server request logs "Accepted", "Closing"

Tags: php, logging, server, silent, php-7.4

After updating from PHP 7.3 to PHP 7.4.8, I have noticed the server has started to log "Accepted", "Closing" for all requests and sometimes: "Closed without sending a request; it was probably just an unused speculative preconnection".

```
[Wed Aug  5 17:51:27 2020] PHP 7.4.8 Development Server (http://localhost:3000) started
[Wed Aug  5 17:51:37 2020] 127.0.0.1:37788 Accepted
[Wed Aug  5 17:51:37 2020] 127.0.0.1:37792 Accepted
[Wed Aug  5 17:51:37 2020] 127.0.0.1:37788 [200]: (null) /
[Wed Aug  5 17:51:37 2020] 127.0.0.1:37788 Closing
```

```
[Wed Aug  5 17:52:02 2020] 127.0.0.1:37808 Closed without sending a request; it was probably just an unused speculative preconnection
[Wed Aug  5 17:52:02 2020] 127.0.0.1:37808 Closing
```

I would like to know if there is an option to start the server in a "silent" mode, where the logs would contain only info, warnings, and errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are starting the PHP server yourself, passing it the `-q` or `--no-header` argument (Quiet-mode) solved it for me:

```
php -q -S 127.0.0.1:8080 index.php
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66864545

Comment: This seems to silence the Accepted and Closing messages, but it also silences all of the info, warnings, and errors. All logs from `error_log()` and `syslog()` are being silenced as well.